# xcode6-beta5 crashes when creating a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdictionary, xcode6-beta5

I'm a little puzzled as to why switching from xcode6-beta4 to xcode6-beta5 would bring breaking changes to my app!  However, here is what I am looking at,

[image: An image of the error, i cannot initialize an Array<NSDictionary>]

This code belongs to a view controller.  I'm not sure what other information could be helpful.  I am just trying things at this point...

[image: Another error replacing swift NSDictionary with an NSDictionary]

and in the console read **fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C**, which leads me to think I can't have an NSDictionary in an Array?

I rewrote it like

`var suggestions:Array<Dictionary<String, String> > = [["str1": "s1", "str2": "s2"]]`

but I don't know why i can't have an NSDictionary in a swift Array.

Comment: "why switching from xcode6-beta4 to xcode6-beta5 would bring breaking changes to my app" — maybe because it's **beta**?? ;)

Comment: Curse you jtbandesss!

Comment: And have fun with the new beta rumored for tomorrow :D

Comment: Beta6 tmrw ? Thank god, I won't spend time trying to fix these bs runtime errors.

Comment: I found that usually rebuilding a project from scratch could resolve this kind of issues. But if beta6 is coming out tomorrow, I will wait ;-)